# Strange behavior with dynamic css stylesheet

Tags: php, css

Many times I have used an css technique that I "learned" by myself. When I depends on a dynamic stylesheet that I can put it on html doc, I use css files that's are not css in fact, they're php files. Example: `style.css.php`. ALWAYS worked. But now I'm getting trouble with this in a strange behavior that I never saw before. My `fundo.css.php` file have this simple format:

```
body {
    background: url(../arquivos/imagens/<?php

// some php functions.. 
echo "coyote.jpg";

?>) top left no-repeat;
}
```

It sends this response to the browser:

```
body {
    background: url(../arquivos/imagens/coyote.jpg) top left no-repeat;
}
```

Beautiful but if browser show the background! On **Firebug** console (as on **Dev Tools** in **Chrome**) in *Network* tab the url that's browser trying to find is:

```
http://localhost:8080/ultimocaso/arquivos/imagens/%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BFcoyote.jpg
```

If I just use an css normal file with that content it works like a charm.

Anyone knows tell me why the hell is happening that and/or how to fix it?

**EDIT**

I'm usgin Adobe Dreamweaver to edit my files and in my Preferences -> New Document the option to include BOM signature is OFF !!

Comment: do your "some php functions" include calls to `include` or `require`? those "strange characters" looke like UTF BOMs, which are probably being inserted by other files

Comment: Yes, there's a include indeed. I found something about this BOMs but I thought it wasn't...

Comment: so you found the problem or not? are you still searching for an answer?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer yet, since I still don't know what's the problem with my `require_once` on this file. All my files are utf-8 encoded and the file the is included doesn't print anything.

Comment: @Kobi I didn't get your point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are including files that have a UTF-8 BOM within your PHP.

Although you cannot see this BOM (Byte Order Mark), you can imagine that the files are including in reality look like this:

```
%EF%BB%BF<?php
echo 'this is myinclude.php';
?>
```

When you use the `include` function, you are effectively importing those characters into your file at the point where you included your code.

```
<?php
// some code
include('myinclude.php');
// some code
?>
```

Is actually interpreted something like:

```
<?php
// some code
?>
%EF%BB%BF
<?php
echo 'this is myinclude.php';
?>
<?php
// some code
?>
```

One way to avoid the BOMs in the middle of your code is to make all includes somewhere where they will have less impact, such as at the beginning of your file. Another way (my personal choice) would be to save your imported files in a format that has no BOM, such as regular UTF-8.